# How to set the ID3DXFont to draw text on the top of a game?

Tags: visual-c++, hook, game-physics, direct3d

I have tried to hook a game,and draw my own text on the game rendered by d3d9.I use ID3DXFont,the text can show on the screen,but sometimes the text can be covered by the other texture in the game.I want to know how to draw my text on the top of the screen?

Comment: You should describe what you have tried so far and be more detailed.

Comment: I can use ID3DXFont to draw my text in a game redered by d3d9 now,but sometimes the text can be covered by the texture in the game.How can I draw the text on the top of the game I hooked?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 layers (renderable textures) 1 for game output 1 for HUD than blend them together using texture staging or shader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.However,the problem is that in d3d9 ID3DXFont is a 2D font solution,i want to use it to draw text on the top of all texture.And the game is hooked by my program.How should I do?